# Clear Datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to refresh the datatablewith new content after click the button but it again shows the previous values also. I tried clear() but it doesn't work for me

```
    protected void btnListItems_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblMessage.Visible = false;
    //lblEnddatse.Visible = true;
    Boolean status = true;
    Util objUtil = new Util();
    String Message = "";
    DateTime SDate = new DateTime();
    DateTime EDate = new DateTime();
    string str = "";
    DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataRow dr;
    String[] s1;
    dt.Clear();

    //DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo();
    s1 = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:/TextFiles");

    for (int i = 0; i <= s1.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            //Add Data Grid Columns with name
            dt.Columns.Add("FileName");
            dt.Columns.Add("GeneratedTime");
        }
        //Get each file information
        FileInfo f = new FileInfo(s1[i]);
        FileSystemInfo f1 = new FileInfo(s1[i]);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        //Get File name of each file name
        dr["FileName"] = f1.Name;
        dr["GeneratedTime"] = f1.CreationTime.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        string a = f1.CreationTime.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        //Insert collected file details in Datatable
        string fromdate = txtFromDate.Text.ToString();
        string todate = txtToDate.Text.ToString();

        if ((DateTime.ParseExact(a.ToString(),"dd/MM/yyyy",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)) >= DateTime.ParseExact(fromdate.ToString(),"dd/MM/yyyy",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {

        if ((DateTime.ParseExact(a.ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)) <= DateTime.ParseExact(todate.ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        }


        if ((f.Length / 1024) > 5000)
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "" + f1.Name + " had reach its size limit.";
        }
        else
        { }

    }
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        gvFileGenStatus.DataSource = dt;
        gvFileGenStatus.DataBind();
    }

}
```

How can I refresh the datagridview displayed data every time I click button after I switch the date.
Thanks For the help in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
gvFileGenStatus.Rows.Clear();
```

Comment: Are you using microsoft's `DataGridView` or its another component?

Answer (score 0):

```
dt.Dispose();

or in 

DataTable dt_null = new DataTable();

if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    gvFileGenStatus.DataSource = dt_null;
    gvFileGenStatus.DataBind();
}
```